# Google Cloud Endpoints - How to implement partial responses?

Tags: response, google-cloud-endpoints, partial, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently developing a proof-of-concept web service in **Java** using **Google Cloud Endpoints** and **Objectify**. Currently I want to implement/define partial responses to client queries to minimize GAE datastore ops.

Here are my researches and observations so far:

On the GAE datastore layer I know there exists the concept of projection queries, which happens during the entity fetch phase, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862936/querying-selected-fields-in-an-entity-in-objectify-appengine). (optimization of datastore ops possible)

On the Google Cloud Endpoints layer I know there exists the concept of field masking, which happens after the entity was fetched from the GAE datastore, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516287/how-do-you-return-a-partial-response-in-app-engine-python-endpoints). (optimization of datastore ops not possible)

From the YouTube-API I know there is this concept of [partial resources](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#partial), which seems to come close to the thing I want to achieve. (optimization of datastore ops already implemented)

Now my questions:

1.) Is there a "simple way" to implement partial responses like it is done in the YouTube-API e.g. using certain configurations or annotations?

2.) If there is no "simple way" to implement partial responses would it be a "preferred way" to decompose entities and build relational entities with different property groups? Then these relational entities could be composed to a partial response entity which is returned to the client. As far as I know the downside of this approach would be that every response entity needs to be saved first before it can be returned to client.

3.) Are there any other preferred solutions to this problem?

Comment: This question sounds like premature optimization. Get your system working with "the simple approach" and then figure out how to optimize it later - if you need that at all. By then you will have significantly more familiarity with the underlying tools and can ask more targeted questions.

Comment: To my knowledge, the YouTube API is not speaking of optimizing database retrieval so much as optimizing network usage. Endpoints supports the same thing, as you said. If you want to support database optimization, then I believe you can inject a `@Named("fields") parameter String fields` into your method, parse it, and convert it into a projection query. However, projection queries require indexes, so I don't know that you can really support arbitrary field masks in this manner.